# Unable to set text at top left for input with height

Tags: reactjs, typescript, input, material-ui

I have a situation in one of my projects, where I have implemented an InputBase of Material UI for textbox purpose, but the issue with textbox is , in iPad the keyboard opens up with dictation , and the client asked us to remove the same, so instead of textbox, I tried for simple Input, after giving a height of 400px , the input box somehow appear bigger, but being as single source of line, the typing starts from the middle of the box, instead of top left of the box.
Anyone has any suggestions for material UI input?

Comment: Can you provide some code example? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<textarea rows="4" cols="50">
```

instead of input

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but textarea will eventually call the dictation on iPad, which is not needed.